# \setcitestyle error in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, errors, natbib, overleaf

I am trying to remove the comma between author and year when using \citet{} in an article class document on Overleaf. So, I have included the following code in the preamble:

```
\setcitestyle{notesep={; }, aysep={ }}
```

However, I get an 'Undefined control sequence' error. This previous post ([Natbib setcitestyle causes "undefined control sequence error"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56525/natbib-setcitestyle-causes-undefined-control-sequence-error)) indicates that the problem is caused by an outdated version of natbib that does not include the \setcitestyle function.

Is it possible to update natbib on Overleaf? However, I would expect that Overleaf would have the most up-to-date version of natbib...

%%%

Update with example code:

Renewing this biblatex command successfully removes comma.

```
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
```

Apparently there is a conflict between natbib and apalike or apacite. See here:
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=23715

Can anyone confirm this? Any advice on best practice when using natbib and the authoryear style in biblatex?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-comp, hyperref=true, backend=biber, natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{natbib}                         % gives error
\setcitestyle{notesep={; }, aysep={ }}          % gives error

%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace} % removes comma, no error

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{kerth_information_2003,
    title = {Information transfer about roosts in female {Bechstein}'s bats: an experimental field study},
    volume = {270},
    journal = {Proceedings of the Royal Society of London. Series B: Biological Sciences},
    author = {Kerth, Gerald and Reckardt, Karsten},
    year = {2003},
    pages = {511--515}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
A thing happen once, the thing was seen by \citet{kerth_information_2003}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot really update packages in Overleaf. You might be able to upload all needed files into your project, but that gets cumbersome quite soon and might cause other trouble down the way (especially due to package dependency). Note thought that the answer you linked to mentions packages from 2010, I'm quite sure Overleaf is more up to date than that. Please shown us an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) of what you are trying to achieve. You might want to confirm you are really loading `natbib`. BTW: your question is tagged `biblatex` do you use that package?

Comment: I can confirm `\usepackage{natbib}\setcitestyle{notesep={; }, aysep={ }}` works fine on Overleaf. Perhaps check that `natbib` was really indeed loaded?

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the advice, this is my first post! I have added some example code that produces the error.

Comment: @LianTzeLim The problem might be a conflict between natbib and apalike. Renewing this biblatex command worked `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `biblatex` and `natbib`. You can get `natbib` support within `biblatex`, but you cannot use `natbib`. This is independent of the Biblatex style you select. It matters not whether it is `apalike` or something else.

Biblatex uses its own interface for formatting the citations and bibliography. It does not use BibTeX `.bst` files, which are at the core of `natbib`'s approach. No BibTeX styles are compatible with Biblatex. They are quite different ways of managing the references and bibliography.

If you want to use Biblatex, you need to stick to Biblatex's interface. If you want `natbib`, drop `biblatex`.

That is, the best practice when using `natbib` and Biblatex, regardless of style, is

## *Don't!*