# Removing spacing between commas in multiple citation

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, punctuation

I am trying to remove the spacing between citation numbers in my manuscript using `elsearticle.cls` template, including `natbib` package, and `model1-num-names` as the `bibliographystyle`. I have tried using some modifiers in my permeable found here on this site, but without giving any errors, none of them worked for me and I still see the spacing between commas. I also tried to use `\setcitestyle` like `\setcitestyle{notesep={}}`, but it gives the undefined control sequence error. Looked up how to resolve the error, did not find a helpful answer ([Natbib setcitestyle causes "undefined control sequence error"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56525/44748)).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164853/197451

Comment: @jsbibra - The earlier posting to which you posted a link works for the `cite` citation management package, but not the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: @jsbibra I need to use natbib.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter you need to change via a `\setcitestyle` instruction is `citesep`, not `notesep`.

[image]

Basically, the solution works by changing the "object" that's inserted between consecutive numeric-style citation call-outs from `,` to `,\kern-\mylen`, where `\mylen` is set to the width of `\space`. `natbib` is hard-coded to insert a space after this object.

Speaking purely for myself, I find the default style, i.e., with spaces after the commas, more pleasing. If you have ranges of numbers and you want to compress them, you may want to specify the document class option `sort&compress`, which will get passed on to the `natbib` package (which, as you probably know already, is loaded automatically by the `elsarticle` document class).

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\space}
\setcitestyle{citesep={,\kern-\mylen}}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{A,author="ABC",title="Thoughts",year=3001}
@misc{B,author="DEF",title="Thoughts",year=3002}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{A,B} --- produced by \verb+\cite+

[1,2] --- hard-coded string \verb+[1,2]+
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I am also fine with spaces, but it seems it is a requirement. So it's not about personal preferences and I should make this work. Also, the problem with setcitestyle is that it gives undefined control sequence with either of its options, and I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: @Hossein - Please note that there is no "undefined control sequence" issue when running `\setcitestyle` in the example code above. If you're getting an error message, it *must* be because your document setup is materially different from what's used above. To me, it sounds like you're maybe not using the `elsarticle` document class. Please state which document class you employ.

Comment: I am using elsearticle document class. still when I load \setcitestyle, it gives me the error. Let me tell you when I use \citestyle, it doesn't give error, but it doesn't do anything either. So I still have the issue of not being able to remove spacing.

Comment: @Hossein - you claim to be using both `\setcitestyle` and `\citestyle`; I’m actually not familiar with the latter command. I also don’t know what you mean by “when I load `\setcitestyle`“, as there is no package with that name. Anyway, since my answer is evidently of absolutely no use to you, should I go ahead and delete it? Please advise.

Comment: I meant I tried both (not using them simultaneously). But let's get back to the original question, and discuss your solution. As you said, I need to use `\setcitestyle{notesep={}}` right? OK, how shouldI exactly put this in my document? I have this:
`\documentclass[preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{notesep={,}}
\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}`

But I get the following error:
`! Undefined control sequence.<recently read> \setcitestyle \setcitestyle`

Comment: @Hossein - **NO**, I did **NOT** say that you should run `\setcitestyle{notesep={}}`. In fact, I wrote that you should *not* modify the `notesep` parameter; instead, you should be modifying the `citesep` parameter.  By the way, the `\biboptions` macro takes six [6!] arguments, not one. Running `\biboptions{numbers,sort&compress}` is bound to lead to disaster. Please check what I actually wrote you should run: `\newlength\mylen \settowidth\mylen{\space} \setcitestyle{citesep={,\kern-\mylen}}`. By the way, the `elsarticle` class loads `natbib` automatically -- no need for `\usepackage{natbib}`.

Comment: I used your solution on overleaf and it worked. Not sure why it doesn't work on my laptop. Anyways, thanks for the efforts!